# Live USB blinks and doesn't boot

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, live-usb, bios

I am completely new to Linux and I am trying to boot live USB for Ubuntu.

I have Asus e203n. I consume it has no OS, because it always opens BIOS Utility - Ez mode. In Boot priority it shows me `UEFI: USB2.0, partition 1`. I have tried with different USB and it also says `UEFI: <name of USB>, partition 1`.
I tried to create live usb with different programs on Windows, like UltraISO and Rufus and with dd utility on my friend's pc with Ubuntu.

When I try to boot it, the screen blinks for millisecond and returns me back to BIOS. That's happening with all live usb that was rewritten in different programs.

I don't have enough knowledge to understand why it's happening. Please, help!

Comment: If the installation media doesn't boot it's probably not viable. What guide did you follow to create bootable media?  Did you verify integrity?  If you don't know what I'm asking - I suggest that you use the BitTorrent link under "alternative downloads" for the ISO and then flash the ISO to USB using balena Etcher.  These methods auto verify and unlike Rufus, etcher does not overwhelm "completely new" users with excessive options whose combinations can result in failed attempts

Comment: I see no actual specifics in your question. What Ubuntu ISO are you trying to write, did you verify as @Nmath suggested? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)  There have been odd *daily* ISOs that haven't booted, which is unlikely your issue but without details we cannot know nor help you.  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview   (most failures in my experience are the result of the write to media.. did you verify that? does it boot on another box?  if it fails on multiple boxes I usually assume bad write..)

Comment: Today I used the BitTorrent link and flashed the ISO using Etcher, and now when I turn on the laptop, there's a black screen that says: "Incompatible license. Aborted. Press any key to exit." :(